# Enable guest user and location services with profile manager

Tags: macos, server.app, system-settings, profile-manager

Is there a way to enable the guest account and location services with profile manager via built in setting or custom ad on?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes and No. As of 10.12 Apple added the option to enable the guest account using a profile and so the answer below is correct for that. As for enabling location services I still to not see a profile option for that but was able to find a a way to do it with a script from another forum. (https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/13723/enabling-location-services-programmatically-via-casper#responseChild109407)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Look for the "Login Window" option in Profile Manager.

Comment: I looked for that option. Does not seem to be there. Running Latest version of 10.10. I see login items but there is no option under those settings

Comment: Agreed.  The option to enable Guest Account is not in the Login Window section as of Server App 5.6.1 and OS 10.13.5.